# Custom command wget without response

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, wget, arduino

I have an arduino with an ethernet shield that is controlling a relay, which control the lights. I usually just use the phone to send a http get request from a widget in tasker, but I would like to be able to just type "light on" or "light_on" in the command line/terminal, and it would turn it on.
I found that I could use `wget` to send the request `wget 192.168.1.177?s=1`, but that is listening for an output afterwards. But the arduino doesn't output anything, it just listens for the get.

So in conclusion, I need to be able to make a custom command, and need a command to customize, to send an http GET request. Don't have to use `wget`, just seemed easiest since it was already installed.

Oh, and my OS is Ubuntu 12. 04 LTS.

Comment: What do you mean by "listening for output"? What happens when you run `wget 192.168.1.177?s=1`? Does the light turn on?

Comment: Yes, the lights do turn on. But in the terminal i have to `ctrl+c` in order to execute another command after. I belive that wget is waiting for the arduino to output some html. Googled, nothing i tried worked. I want it to send the get request and then stop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use netcat for that task; for example, using Nmap's `ncat` incarnation:

`$ echo -e "GET /?s=1 HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: 192.168.1.10\r\n\r\n" | ncat 192.168.1.177`

That is, assuming your Arduino is listening on port 80; otherwise you'll need to specify that after the IP address in ncat's invocation

Afterwards, if that works fine for you, you can make an alias with that entire command, such as appending this to your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_aliases` or whatever you find convenient:

`alias light_on='echo -e "GET /?s=1 HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: 192.168.1.10\r\n\r\n" | ncat 192.168.1.177'`

Comment: i installed nmap, but the request just times out.
`echo -e "GET /?s=1 HTTP/1.0\nHost: 192.168.1.177\r\n\r\n" | ncat 192.168.1.177
`
 and 
`echo -e "GET /?s=1 HTTP/1.0\nHost: 192.168.1.67\r\n\r\n" | ncat 192.168.1.177
`


my ip = 192.168.1.67
arduino ip = 192.168.1.177

Comment: You're missing one `\r` character in your command, right after `HTTP/1.0`, check that out.

Comment: still doesn't work

`echo -e "GET /?s=0 HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: 192.168.1.67\r\n\r\n" | ncat 192.168.1.177`

Comment: Why did you change the parameter `s=1` to `s=0`? I don't know if that's relevant for your listening program, but it seems so.

Comment: s=1 turns the lamp on, and s=0 turns it off. i tried both, i guess i copied the 2nd line.

    s = state, 0 = off, 1 = on.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that; my point was whether you were trying to turn the lamp on with s=0 accidentally, which would not work. So, what's the output of the command? Try appending verbose flags to netcat, like `ncat -vv 192.168.1.177` and paste here what it says.